# pyinstaller EXE OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll

Tags: pyinstaller, executable, libspatialindex

I am using Window 10 64bit to create exe. However, the exe gives error below:
**File "rtree\core.py", line 126, in 
OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll
[23324] Failed to execute script microwave_python_code**

I tried below solutions ppl shared but still cannot solve the problem.

1. --add-data=C:\path\to\spatialindex_c-64.dll;. to my build command
2. pip uninstall rtree then install using 'Rtree-0.9.4-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl'
3. install 'spatialindex-src-1.9.3.tar.gz'
4. copied the 'spatialindex_c-64.dll'  into rtee site package folder
5. copied the 'spatialindex_c-64.dll'  into exe folder

Anyone able to create working exe by doing above?
I still face problem after trying above solutions. Anything else that I can do to get my exe works?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and I solved it using the final answer on http://pyinstaller.47505.x6.nabble.com/OSError-while-running-exe-td2997.html.

To solve it, find the `.specs` file that is made when building the .exe, and add two things to it:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_dynamic_libs
...
a = Analysis(...
            binaries=collect_dynamic_libs("rtree"),
            ...)
```

That will find the `.dll` files used by `rtree`.
After that, you can rebuild it with the command `pyinstaller your_script_name.spec`.

Comment: I have the same problem and If I print out `collect_dynamic_libs("rtree")` in .spec file, I get empty list. I assume it is not desirable output. Any idea why it is like this?