# OSError when executing PyInstaller .exe file - "could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll"

Tags: pyinstaller, r-tree, oserror

I'm trying to make an executable file using pyinstaller. When running the exe from the command line I get the error "could not find spatialindex_c-64.dll".

Things I have tried so far:

1. Uninstall and reinstall rtree
2. Create fresh environment, only installing packages with conda install (not condaforge)
3. Importing rtree directly in my script
4. Editing spec file following advice in [pyinstaller EXE OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398516/pyinstaller-exe-oserror-could-not-find-or-load-spatialindex-c-64-dll)
5. Editing spec file to specify rtree as hidden import
6. Copying dll file over to dist directory

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to fix this?